# Format JSON file to be read localhost?

Tags: javascript, json

I dont know if I am formatting my .json wrong but I am using backbone.js and cannot pass in the `url` to my json file.

```
PlayersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: Player,
      url: 'http://localhost/STEPS/data/players.json',
      //localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("players-backbone"),
});
```

The .json looks like a standard json format.

```
[
    {
         name: 'Kobe Bryant',
         team: 'Los Angeles Lakers',
         team_id: 1,
         number: 24
    },
    {
         name: 'Lebron James',
         team: 'Miami Heat',
         team_id: 2,
         number: 6
    }
]
```

I just copied and pasted that into a blank file then saved it as players.json I felt maybe there is more to it than that. I searched the web but I just want a simple way to store a dummy .json file in my localhost for access via url in backbone.

In a tutorial I followed a while back the url they targeted was this http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users

Comment: json is invalid...  paste it in jsonlint.com. The number one rule of JSON is double quotes for keys and strings

Comment: That's how you create js objects. Json is in this form: `"key" : "value"` the double quotes are required to be valid JSON.

Comment: Oh really? I saw that inside http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users the keys and strings used double quotes I went in added single quotes because I just thought quotes were needed, Ill try that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys, its reading them as models now :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the JSON to look something like this.  At least this is valid.

```
{ "players": [
    {
        "name": "Kobe Bryant",
        "team": "Los Angeles Lakers",
        "team_id": 1,
        "number": 24
    },
    {
        "name": "Lebron James",
        "team": "Miami Heat",
        "team_id": 2,
        "number": 6
    }
]}
```

Comment: well they said it above in the comments but you posted as an answer, well actually re reading it that is not how the json should be formatted for my backbone app.. the double quotes is correct though. that solved my problem